# How to create Share Button to Hi5

Tags: php, ajax, json, social-networking, javascript

Everyone else social networks have a simple method to share anything content. I need create a share button using php/javascript. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of services that do a great job at this for free. All you need to do is paste in a little JavaScript snippet. Try:

- http://sharethis.com/
- http://www.addthis.com/
- http://www.addtoany.com/

Facebook goes a bit further with a bunch of other drop-in widgets:

- http://developers.facebook.com/plugins

Comment: Thanks Foofy, but none of them have an option to post to hi5 Wall. I tried with The Gigya Plugin http://www.gigya.com/ But, I need post to Hi5 Status and Gigya doesn't have that option.